# JSON to MVC Object from an Ajax Post

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this json array-ish variable which gets values from a table:

```
var data = { "Model": [] };
$(".student-grade-data-row").each(function () {
    data.Model.push({
        'subjectId' : currentSubjectId,
        'studentId': $(this).attr('id'),
        'grade1' : $(this).find(".grade-select").val(),
        'mult' : $(this).find(".mult-select").val(),
        'subject': $(this).find(".topic-input").val(),
    });
});
```

It was made to resemble a MVC class called `grade`

```
public partial class grade
{
    public int id { get; set; } //auto-set
    public int subjectId { get; set; }
    public string studentId { get; set; }
    public int grade1 { get; set; }
    public int mult { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; } //auto-set
}
```

Now in the perfect world, I would like to have the values inside the **data** variable to be send into my controller like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/SendGrades',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (dt) {
        console.log(dt);
    }
});
```

And there I could pick it up, and serialize it as a proper object list.

The problem isI cannot even get a glimpse of what really am I sending to the controller and how possibly could I link it to the object.

I tried making the function take an agrument of type `List<grade> Model`, but It would keep telling me the value is null.

---

I tried using some basic serialization but cant get it to work either. The code

```
public ActionResult SendGrades(JsonResult Model)
{
    List<grade> g = new List<grade>();
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(grade));
    g = (List<grade>)serializer.ReadObject(Model);
    return Content("Hi");
}
```

Gives me an error saying

> Cannot convert from System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult to System.IO.Stream

What would be the proper way to do this so I could later safely store the values in my database?

I'm fairly new to this type of work so I apologize for any noob-ism.
Any help would be great here.

Comment: Change the method to `public ActionResult SendGrades(List<grade> Model)` (and always use `url: 'Url.Action("SendGrades", "Ajax")',` to generate the correct url). You also need to set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: This method, when tested claims to return empty variables. If I run return content(Model.First().subject) I'll get a NULL error. 
I'm using a separate js file to send values. Is this possible to use `Url.Action`?

Comment: Did you see the edited comment (regarding setting the `contentType` option)?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the answer now

Comment: And you cannot use razor code in an external file, but you can pass it to the js file e.g. just use `var url = '@Url.Action(..)';` to create a global variable in the main view, or use a `data-url="@Url.Action(..)"` to assign it in the element that triggers the ajax

Comment: You should set the options specifically i.e. - `url: ..., data: JSON.stringify(data), contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", success: function (data) { ....` (and just tested it and it works fine)

Comment: Well it doesn't work at all for me. Updated the question again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133776/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-aln447).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ajax options needs to include

```
type: 'POST'
```

By default, its a `GET` which has no body, therefore setting `contentType` is pointless and the `DefaultModelBinder` will not use the `JsonValueProvider` (for a `GET`, the format of the data would have needed to be `data: { [0]subjectId: value, [0]studentId: value, [1]subjectId: value, [0]studentId: value, ....etc }` - i.e. indexed property names)

The full code needs to be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/SendGrades',
    type: 'POST', // add this
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (dt) {
        console.log(dt);
    }
});
```

And the controller method

```
public ActionResult SendGrades(List<grade> model)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this. add one more class contains the list of grade as a property

```
class Models
{
    public List<grade> Model{get; set;}
}
```

and change your Method like this

```
public ActionResult SendGrades(Models models)
{
    List<grade> g = models.Model;
    //then write your logic here
}
```

Comment: Same error as for doing it the `SendGrades(List<grade> Model)` way

Answer (score 0):

Your Model should be like

```
public partial class grade
{
    public int id { get; set; } //auto-set
    public int subjectId { get; set; }
    public string studentId { get; set; }
    public int grade1 { get; set; }
    public int mult { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; } //auto-set
}
```

and when u send data to server assign data using `data.Model`  cause u are setting value to Model

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Ajax/SendGrades',
    type: "POST",
    data: data.Model, //try to change it in ur code first if not work use jquery.post
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (dt) {
    console.log(dt);
    }
});
```

or Use Jquery Post

```
$.post('/Ajax/SendGrades', data.Model,
       function(data){
        console.log(data);
       });
```

and In Controller

```
public ActionResult SendGrades(List<grade> Model)
{
      //then write your logic here
}
```